Why can't I std::bind_front a function to std::apply?
What if I have a range of pairs and I want to generate a new range from the reduction of those pairs? So my overly "std::" loving brain thought of this:
auto vec_of_pairs = std::vector {
    std::pair {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 11},
};

auto reduced_view = vec_of_pairs | std::views::transform(
        std::bind_front(std::apply, std::multiplies()));

auto reduced = std::vector(reduced_view.begin(), reduced_view.end());

This didn't compile, saying that std::bind_front did not match the parameter list because std::apply had an unknown type, which makes sense because it's a template. So I tried explicitly stating the function and tuple passed to it:
auto reduced_view = vec_of_pairs | std::views::transform(
            std::bind_front(std::apply<std::multiplies<void>, std::pair<int, int>>, std::multiplies()));

Quite a bit messier, but it still didn't fix the problem. This time I get a much less descriptive error, saying there was no matching "|" operator (note that explicitly declaring that the std::multiplies function with int doesn't seem to behave differently from void).
Could anyone please tell me why this isn't possible/what I'm doing wrong?

You are not allowed to take the address of a standard template function.

Although change bind_front(apply<multiplies<void>, pair<int, int>>, ...)) to bind_front(apply<const multiplies<void>&, const pair<int, int>&>, ...)) can fix the problem.

Thank you so much! Can you explain why this works? And is there a cleaner way of doing it?

std::views::transform([](const std::pair<int>& p) { return p.first * p.second; }) Would this be considered clean?

fair enough, i was just wondering if there was a way to avoid using a lambda. i find it fun to try and use only the standard library with these types of things, write nothing myself. I also wanted to avoid using the pair directly, and was hoping to replicate the sort of unpacking of tuples you can do in Rust's closures. std::apply seemed like the tool to use but looks like i can't do it very elegantly.

In C++23 you can use zip_transform to avoid lambda, demo.

You actually cannot take an address of most standard library functions.

@康桓瑋 i tried using zip_transform like this: std::views::zip_transform(std::multiplies(), vec_of_pairs) and the compiler says there is no instance of the template that this binds to. Did I use the function incorrectly?

std::apply is a template function, not a function object with ovverloaded function call operators. There's no std type to represent a function template. So, you're gonna need to lower your expectations this time and write a little bit of own code. I'd be happier if all std static function templates were replaced with CPO, but we need to deal with facts.
